# When should we use a struct as opposed to an enum?

Tags: struct, enums, rust

Structs and enums are similar to each other.

When would it be better to use a struct as opposed to an enum (or vice-versa)?  Can someone give a clear example where using a struct is preferable to using an enum?

Comment: Another small detail: `pub enum` makes all details (variants and their fields) public, `pub struct` still keeps the fields private by default.  If you need to expose `enum` data in a public interface but want to hide the details, you need to wrap the (private) `enum` in a `pub struct`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps the easiest way to explain the fundamental difference is that an enum contains "variants", of which you can only ever have one at a time, whereas a struct contains one or more fields, *all* of which you must have.

So you might use an `enum` to model something like an error code, where you can only ever have one at a time:

```
enum ErrorCode {
    NoDataReceived,
    CorruptedData,
    BadResponse,
}
```

Enum variants can contain values if needed. For example, we could add a case to `ErrorCode` like so:

```
enum ErrorCode {
    NoDataReceived,
    CorruptedData,
    BadResponse,
    BadHTTPCode(u16),
}
```

In this case, an instance of `ErrorCode::BadHTTPCode` always contains a `u16`.

This makes each individual variant behave kind of like either a [tuple struct or unit struct](https://rustbyexample.com/custom_types/structs.html):

```
// Unit structs have no fields
struct UnitStruct;

// Tuple structs contain anonymous values.
struct TupleStruct(u16, &'static str);
```

However, the advantage of writing them as enum variants is that each of the cases of `ErrorCode` can be stored in a value of type `ErrorCode`, as below (this would not be possible with unrelated structs).

```
fn handle_error(error: ErrorCode) {
    match error {
        ErrorCode::NoDataReceived => println!("No data received."),
        ErrorCode::CorruptedData => println!("Data corrupted."),
        ErrorCode::BadResponse => println!("Bad response received from server."),
        ErrorCode::BadHTTPCode(code) => println!("Bad HTTP code received: {}", code)
    };
}

fn main() {
    handle_error(ErrorCode::NoDataReceived); // prints "No data received."
    handle_error(ErrorCode::BadHTTPCode(404)); // prints "Bad HTTP code received: 404"
}
```

You can then `match` on the enum to determine which variant you've been given, and perform different actions depending on which one it is.

---

By contrast, the third type of struct that I didn't mention above is the most commonly used - it's the type of struct that everyone is referring to when they simply say "struct".

```
struct Response {
    data: Option<Data>,
    response: HTTPResponse,
    error: String,
}

fn main() {
    let response = Response {
        data: Option::None,
        response: HTTPResponse::BadRequest,
        error: "Bad request".to_owned()
    }
}
```

Note that in that case, in order to create a `Response`, all of its fields must be given values.

Also, the way that the value of `response` is created (i.e. `HTTPResponse::Something`) implies that `HTTPResponse` is an enum. It might look something like this:

```
enum HTTPResponse {
    Ok,         // 200
    BadRequest, // 400
    NotFound,   // 404
}
```

Comment: What about structs that implement a trait? (i.e trait HTTPResponse, and structs Ok, BadRequest, NotFound). Would the difference be that structs that implement traits have different method implementations, but enums are required to have the same method implementations?

Comment: @Taztingo If I understand what you're asking correctly, then the answer is yes, that's one of the significant differences: the trait could be implemented differently for each of the structs, whereas you implement a trait once for an entire enum. However, you could always match on `self` in the trait method implementations, and create effectively different implementations for each variant.

Answer (score 2):

Enums have multiple possibilities. Structs have only one possible "type" of thing they can be. Mathematically, we say a struct is a product type and an enum is a sum of products. If you only have one possibility, use a struct. For example, a point in space is *always* going to be three numbers. It's never going to be a string, or a function, or something else. So it should be a struct containing three numbers. On the other hand, if you're building a mathematical expression, it could be (for instance) a number or two expressions joined by an operator. It has multiple possibilities, so it should be an enum.

In short, if a struct works, use a struct. Rust can optimize around it, and it's going to be clearer to anyone reading your code what the value is supposed to be treated as.

Comment: What do you mean by "Rust can optimize around it"? By the time you get to codegen, structs are really just enums with a single variant, so they should be identical for optimization purposes.

Answer (score 0):

An `Enum` is a type with a constrained set of values.

```
enum Rainbow {
    Red,
    Orange,
    Yellow,
    Green,
    Blue,
    Indigo,
    Violet
}

let color = Red;

match color {
    Red => { handle Red case },
    // all the rest would go here
}
```

You can store data in the Enum if you need it.

```
enum ParseData {
    Whitespace,
    Token(String),
    Number(i32),
}

fn parse(input: String) -> Result<String, ParseData>;
```

A struct is a way to represent a thing.

```
struct Window {
    title: String,
    position: Position,
    visible: boolean,
}
```

Now you can make new `Window` objects that represent a window on your screen.