# How to store and access from impl based on an enum?

Tags: rust

I have the following impl that is based on an enum. I have no idea how I am supposed store and access my values from it now.

Here's the impl:

```
pub enum Baz {
    // My data structure has a string and a number
    Foo(String),
    Bar(u64),
}

impl Baz {
    pub fn get(baz: Baz) -> String {
        let mut result = "".to_string();
        match baz {
            Baz::Foo(v) => {},
            Baz::Bar(v) => { result = v.to_string() },
        }
        result
    }
    pub fn new() {
        // Do I even need new() for instance creation?!
        println!("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Here's how I access it:

```
mod bazbazbaz;
use bazbazbaz::baz;

fn main() {
    let x: data::Baz;
    x::Foo("mystring".to_string());
    x::Bar(42);
    x.get(Baz::Bar); // I expect "42" here as string
}
```

Is it just a syntax mistake, or am I misunderstanding the concept in general?

Comment: I took the liberty of moving the code verbatim into the question from those links. However, you may wish to improve your code further. In particular, can you reproduce the issue without nested modules? A link to the code in the [Rust Playground](//play.rust-lang.org) would also be quite useful. Also, please see what makes a proper [MCVE].

Comment: Have you taken the time to read the excellent (free!) book [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/)? Your code shows some gaps in knowledge about Rust concepts like methods and enums that are covered by this introductory resource. There's entire chapters dedicated to [enums](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch06-00-enums.html) and [methods](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch05-03-method-syntax.html).

Answer (score 4):

I think you're confusing the concept of a [struct](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch05-00-structs.html) with the concept of an [enum](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch06-00-enums.html).

Structs *struct*ure your data in a certain way, while enums present *enum*erated choices for how to structure data.

```
struct Baz {
    foo: String,
    bar: u64
}
```

This holds a `String` *and* a `u64`.

```
enum Baz {
    Foo(String),
    Bar(u64),
}
```

This holds a `String` *or* a `u64`.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it just a syntax mistake, or am I misunderstanding the concept in general?

You're misunderstanding the concept in general. Buckle up...

---

> ```
> pub enum Baz {  
>     // My data structure has a string and a number  
>     Foo(String),
>     Bar(u64),
> }
> ```

Your data structure does not have a string and a number. Your data structure is either a `Baz::Foo`, in which case it contains a `String`, or a `Baz::Bar`, in which case it contains a `u64`.

It appears that what you're looking for is not an `enum`, but a `struct`.

```
pub struct Baz {
    foo: String,
    bar: u64,
}
```

This struct, unlike your enum, contains a string *and* a number.

This is an illustration of the general difference, which is that enums list different "variants", of which instances can be *one and only one*. In your definition, `Foo` and `Bar` are *variants*.

Structs, on the other hand, define a list of fields, *all of which* must be present in instances. If you want a more detailed explanation, please see [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48756348/6073823), or as @Shepmaster suggested in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49539321/how-to-store-and-access-from-impl-based-on-an-enum#comment86088407_49539321), take a look at *The Rust Programming Language*.

---

> ```
> fn main() {
>     let x: data::Baz;
>     x::Foo("mystring".to_string());
>     x::Bar(42);
>     x.get(Baz::Bar); // I expect "42" here as string
> }
> ```

Again, I can see what you're trying to do. The intention is to create an instance of `Baz`, store it in `x`, set the string to `"mystring"`, and set the number to `42`. However, because `Baz` is an enum, what you're actually doing is creating two separate instances of `Baz`:

```
fn main() {
    // This creates a `Baz::Foo` containing a string, and stores it
    // in `foo`.
    let foo = Baz::Foo("mystring".to_string());

    // This creates a `Baz::Bar` containing a number, and stores it
    // in `bar`.
    let bar = Baz::Bar(42);

    // You can get the value out in a number of ways. This is one:
    match foo {
        Baz::Foo(string) => println!("{}", string), // prints "mystring"
        Baz::Bar(number) => println!("{}", number),
    }

    match bar {
        Baz::Foo(string) => println!("{}", string),
        Baz::Bar(number) => println!("{}", number), // prints "42"
    }
}
```

What you want to do instead, using the definition of `Baz` as a `struct`, is the following:

```
fn main() {
    let qux = Baz {
        foo: "mystring".to_string(),
        bar: 42,
    };

    // Get the value of `foo` and print it.
    println!("{}", qux.foo); // prints "mystring"

    // Get the value of `bar` and print it.
    println!("{}", qux.bar); // prints "42"
}
```